# Trouble pausing AVAudioPlayer in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, audio

I have build a tableview to play a series of sounds. I have a unique sound file tied to each index of the tableview. I cannot get the sound to pause when the tableview cell is tapped a second time.

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        if indexPath.row == 0 {

            do {

                sound1 = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL.init(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "sound1_audio", ofType: "mp3")!))
                sound1?.prepareToPlay()
            }
            catch {
                print(error)
            }
            if sound1!.isPlaying {
                sound1!.pause();
            } else {
                sound1!.play();
            }

        } else if indexPath.row == 1 {

            do {

                sound2 = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL.init(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "sound2_audio", ofType: "mp3")!))
                sound2?.prepareToPlay()
            }
            catch {
                print(error)
            }
            if sound2!.isPlaying {
                sound2!.pause()
            } else {
                sound2!.play();
            }
```

Comment: is line `sound1!.pause()` called ?

Comment: please excuse my ignorance...how an I verify that?

Comment: you can put breakpoint on that line, run the app and simulate your case, then you will see if its called. Here you can learn how to set breakpoints:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/12697473/6570914